# Confusion about predicting using `glm()` logistic regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

I have been provided a sample logistic regression as follows:

```r
glm(formula = output ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X1:term + 
               term:X5 - 1, family="binomial", data=mydata)
```

I am not too familiar with logistic regression, so I have a few questions about how to properly predict on a new test set using this model:

1. Unlike a regular regression, I cannot simply 'plug-in' the variables and get a meaningful numeric output. Instead, I must first set a threshold probability above which values will be 1 and below which values will be 0. Is this correct?
2. I cannot make use of this sample model or get the same results as the person who provided it until I have the probability threshold that was used for prediction. Is this correct?
3. If I wanted to split the outputs into tiers, would I use the probabilities for that and map them to some other value? How would that process work (feel free to let me know if this is out of scope).

Comment: Don't split the probabilities.  They are meant to be used continuously.  For the other questions some in-depth background reading about logistic regression would help.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Agreed, though I imagine this could help others who are being introduced to logistic regression through glm and are unclear on interpretation.